# How to match decimal numbers starting with '!' in C++

Tags: c++, regex

How do I match all the decimal numbers starting with "!" (bang) in the given string? I have written the following code but it fails with an assert

```
#include<iostream>
#include<regex>

int main()
{
    std::string s1("{!112,2,3}");
    std::regex e(R"(\!\d+)", std::regex::grep);

    std::cout << s1 << std::endl;

    std::sregex_iterator iter(s1.begin(), s1.end(), e);
    std::sregex_iterator end;

    while(iter != end)
    {
        std::cout << "size: " << iter->size() << std::endl;

        for(unsigned i = 0; i < iter->size(); ++i)
        {
            std::cout << "the " << i + 1 << "th match" << ": " << (*iter)[i] << std::endl;
        }
        ++iter;
    }
}
```

assert

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
  what():  regex_error
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: what integers start with !?

Comment: i dont think you need the `\!` just `!`. Its not a special character

Comment: just `!` does not work either

Comment: GCC runs this fine, while Clang gives me more info than in the question: *An empty regex is not allowed in the POSIX grammar.*

Comment: The above assert is with g++ 5.4

Comment: First, make sure yoy are using the latest Gcc compiler. Then use `R"(!(\d+))"` pattern and grab `(*iter)[1]`.

Comment: That works! Thank @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you are using the latest GCC compiler.

Then use `R"(!(\d+))"` pattern that matches an exclamation mark and then captures one or more digits Iinto Group 1.

Then just grab `(*iter)[1]` that holds your values while iterating the matches.

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/NgJPI9):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<regex>
int main() {
   std::string s1("{!112,2,3} {!346,765,8}"); 
   std::regex e(R"(!(\d+))"); 
   std::cout << s1 << std::endl; 
   std::sregex_iterator iter(s1.begin(), s1.end(), e); std::sregex_iterator end;   
   while(iter != end) { 
       std::cout << "Value: " << (*iter)[1] << std::endl; 
       ++iter; 
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{!112,2,3} {!346,765,8} 
Value: 112
Value: 346
```